# Evaluate Polynomial Function

Tags: c

Not sure where I'm going wrong in this, and it has to be in my polyEvaluate function, but any help would be appreciated. The problem is coming in the final calculation. I've tried modifying the function but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double polyEvaluate(double coefficients[], int order, double x)
{
    int i, j;
    double polyExp[order], polyProd[order];
    double sum;
    double constant = coefficients[order];
    double temp;

    for(i=order-1; i>0; i--){
        polyExp[i]=pow(x, i);
    }

    j=order;
    i=0;

    while (i<j){
        temp=polyExp[i];
        polyExp[i]=polyExp[j];
        polyExp[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    for(i=0; i<order; i++){
        polyProd[i]=coefficients[i] * polyExp[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<order; i++) {
        sum+=polyProd[i];
    }

    sum+=constant;

    return(sum);
}

int main(void)
{
    int order, i;
    double input;
    double coefficients[order+1];

    printf("Enter the order of the polynomial: ");
    scanf("%d", &order);

    printf("\nEnter the coefficients: \n");

    for(i=0; i<=order; i++)
    {
        printf(" >> ");
        scanf("%lf", &coefficients[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &input);

    printf("\nThe value of the function is: %lf", polyEvaluate(coefficients, order, input));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your evaluation routine should have one well-defined loop. Your code is overly complicated and probably also is one off as regards the order. (Unlike usual C arrays' length, the order is inclusive: A quadratic polynom has order 2 and three terms.)

Comment: At the time you define your array for the coefficients: `coefficients[order + 1]`, `order` isn't initialised and has an indeterminate value. Read `order` before craeting the array.

Comment: You never fill in `polyExp[0]`. Change the `for` loop to use `i >= 0` instead of `i > 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function to evaluate the polynom is way to complicated. A mathematical representation of the polynom could look like this:

```
    f(x) = ∑ c[i]∙xⁱ
```

There's no need to make the constant a special case, it is `c[0]∙x⁰`. This formula is represented in C as:

```
    double polyEvaluate(double coeff[], int order, double x)
    {
        double res = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
            res += coeff[i] * pow(x, i);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

This simple code requires that the index of the coefficient refers to the exponent, which is a more natural representation for the evaluation function. If you want the user to enter the coefficients with the large exponents first, this should in my opinion be handled once during the input.

(You reverse of the auxiliary array `polyExp`, but that's not really needed; it would be enough to access the coefficient with `order - i` when you sum the terms. Still, it is better to choose a representation that represents your code well in code. With your current code, you create an auxiliary array and reverse it for *every* evaluation.)

You can evaluate the polynom without the `pow` function and hence without the math library, just calculate the power of `x` as you go:

```
    double polyEvaluate(double coeff[], int order, double x)
    {
        double fact = 1.0;
        double res = 0.0;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
            res += coeff[i] * fact;
            fact *= x;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is probably the variable length array you have defined as length `order + 1` while `order` doesn't have a value assigned at that point in time.

I'd advise to stick with fixed-length arrays for the time being (just make them long enough).