# How do I find the first rational zero of a polynomial in C?

Tags: c

I'm a newbie to the C programming and I would like to ask how do I make a program in C that would find the first rational zero of a polynomial ax<sup>3</sup> + bx<sup>2</sup> + cx + d with a few conditions:

1. a is fixed to 1
2. Once the first rational zero is found, the integer will be displayed and program will be stopped.
3. If no rational zero is found, a message "No rational zero found!" will be displayed.

This is an example of the output:

[image: This is the example of the output]

I've done some of the codes by following the example output but I couldn't figure out the "Find the first rational zero" part.
These are my codes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    int a = 1, b, c, d;
    int i;
    int x;
    
    printf("\nInsert value of b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    
    printf("\nInsert value of c: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    
    printf("\nInsert value of d: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    
    printf("\nThe polynomial is %dx^3 + %dx^2 + %dx + %d", a, b, c, d);
    
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------");
    
    printf("\nPossible rational zeros are: ");
    
    for (i=1; i <= d; ++i)
    {
        if (d % i == 0)
        printf("\n%d\n%d", i, -i);
    }
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like an algebra problem then a programming problem.

Comment: Yes finding the first rational zero is an algebra question but they want us to create a program that will help us to find the solution for this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How would you solve the problem by hand? It is only possible to write code when you know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Rational != integer

Comment: @MadPhysicist: For a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, all rational zeros are integers.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534745/suppose-alpha-is-a-rational-root-of-a-monic-polynomial-in-mathbbzx-pr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation you show already lists the possible rational roots using a specialization of the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) where a is fixed to 1.

Hence what you need to do is to check for each possibility `i` and `-i` if it is indeed a root of the polynomial, i.e. evaluate the polynomial for `x=i` and `x=-i` and see if the result is 0.

Comment: May I know how can I write the code to evaluate the polynomial for x=i and x=-i? How can I save the all the values of i and put them into a polynomial to find the result of 0?

Comment: @NewbieInC For evaluating the polynomial, you should store the coefficients in an array, e.g. `int coef[4];`. Since this is homework, please, give it a try yourself (maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900255/evaluate-polynomial-function). If you want to optimize, you may have a look at [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).